# Android - Using CoordinatorLayout in Activity and in Fragment

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

So I am using CoordinatorLayout in the Activity like..

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout> // For Fragments
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `Toolbar` uses `scroll|enterAlways` as `Scrollflags`.

In one specific Fragment, I want to achieve a Parallax effect on a layout and I use `CoordinatorLayout` again, but this causes the Toolbar to not behaving normally.

Here's how I use it in the `Fragment`'s layout :

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <Toolbar/>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppbarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout/> // Contains the Fragment's content
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to achieve both effects? Is it not possible because `Fragment`'s `CoordinatorLayout` intercepts the event?

[image: Rough Layout]

So the toolbar is hidden on scroll, and I need the Search Functionalities to be hidden using parallax effect on scroll

Comment: One `CoordinatorLayout` is enough. Too may cooks spoil the broth.

Comment: Anyway, why duplicate what's in the activity (appbar, toolbar, coordinator) in the fragment when you'll end up putting the fragment back into the activity? What do you intent to implement? A photo maybe?

Comment: @ElvisChweya Oh I thought appbar has to be the direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` :( yes it's for something like that, for a search function.. The search should use parallax effect on user scroll..

Comment: Could you sketch how you envision the layout? I think duplicating is overkill

Comment: @ElvisChweya I felt so too, but I don't know how else can I solve the problem.. Let me do something in paint

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try it, but [this gist](https://gist.github.com/karthikrg/0948bf5d7864c0376bcd) seems teorically a right approach, as it adds  to a CoordinatorLayout a scrollingchild ability to dispatch scrolling to up too.

**Update:**

Tried removing the method `offsetChildToAnchor`, as it is not visible outside of the package.

Then found a [forked gist](https://gist.github.com/NaikSoftware/47cefca5c60e408fa9beb209c4958686) that fixes an issue on scrolling management, and sets `NestedScrollingEnabled` as true.

Added `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on the nested CoordinatorLayout.

Tested nesting two CoordinatorLayouts on an activity without fragment. It works. And should work with a fragment too.

Comment: Came accross that gist too and tried using it, but haven't gotten any luck with it, the part `offsetChildToAnchor` doesn't seem to be in `CoordinatorLayout` as AS said it's not overriding any method in its superclass

Comment: I tried by myself too: yes, the method is not visible outside of the original package. So, as that method only manages the optimization, I am trying  without it in order to maintain the scroll methods. I will update the reply.

Comment: This weekend I've been testing other similar apps as mine and they don't have that kind of overkill multiple `CoordinatorLayout` lol.. Is this a bad design then? Should I just leave the toolbar be? It is just stuck up there, not moving with scroll, and that's it

Comment: In my opinion nesting CoordinatorLayout isnt so bad design.

Comment: My opinion was the same until someone said that it's kinda too much lol I forgot who said that.. Because I've read it once that it can be used to make a snackbar to be at wherever I want it to be